# An infinitely generated abelian group with finite orders of elements and which is not isomorphic to a direct sum of its subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to know if a group G with all of the following properties exist

1) G is infinitely generated

2) G is abelian

3) every element of G has finite order

4) G is not isomorphic to a direct sum of its subgroups

Comment: Doe $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ look good?

Comment: I thought about it, but i don't know why 4) is true for it

Comment: Well, $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of its subgroups $(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)(p)$.

Comment: You should explain what *direct sum of its subgroups* in 4) means. You certainly do not consider *all* subgroups, so which do you take? Do you perhaps mean that $G$ is not isomorphic to a direct sum of finite cyclic groups?

Comment: I think that it should be just a direct sum of non trivial subgroups, may be not cyclic

Comment: The $p$-primary component (with $p$ any prime) of ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$ would work. This group is often denoted by ${\mathbb Z}_{p^\infty}$, and it is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of all complex $p^k$-th roots of unity with $k \ge 0$.

Comment: "$G$ is not isomorphic to a direct sum of its subgroups" makes little sense. Maybe you mean $G$ is not **equal** to the direct product of two **nontrivial subgroups**, or equivalently that $G$ is not **isomorphic** to the direct product of two **nontrivial groups**. This is called "$G$ is (directly) indecomposable".

Comment: To make the question a bit more difficult, maybe assume that for some prime $p$, the set of elements of order $p$ is infinite.